PDO changed behaviour for automatic transactions with PDO in PHP 8
I recently came across some code I have not touched for a while, but wanted to run it. And it failed, although I am almost sure it used to work. So I investigated, and it turns out: it is the transaction handling that has changed from PHP 7.x to 8.x with autocommit=0. I did search PHPs changelog but could not find any indication. I was hoping anybody can clear my mind, because after some investigation I might have also misunderstood how it is supposed to work.
To the problem: in PHP 8.x when I call PDO::beginTransaction() it throws an error if any queries happened before that, supposedly because the queries before automatically opened a transaction (Message is There is already an active transaction). Prior to PHP 8, the same code used to work, as it appears to me after testing that PDO::beginTransaction() would have had committed any open transaction. I have attached code to the bottom, that reproduces this behaviour.

The first question would be about the autocommit mode. The documentation is pretty scarce about that matter and also did not find anything about changes in PHP 8 changelogs. Any ideas where I can find more info?
Why do my selects need (and automatically open) a transaction? There is nothing to rollback anyway. It is particularly painful if you do not want to use autocommit to have implicit write management in your code, but any library, or the sort that queries the database causes failures. Is this how it is supposed to work? Can we somehow make select transactional on their own without affecting writes?
I do get that PHP 7.x probably had errored behaviour. I was under the impression it simply did auto commit any selects, but it seems like also writes are affected. So beginTransaction() then automatically commits even though autocommit is turned off.
Can I somehow prevent transactions from being automatically opened? At the moment the error occurs only when I open a transaction validly, but I do not have any information where a query might have occurred that opened the transaction.

The code used for testing:
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\', autocommit=0');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, false);

$sql = 'SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = 1';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$pdo->beginTransaction();
try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test(`id`, `value`) VALUES(2, "Test")');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test(`value`) VALUES("Missing ID")');
    $stmt->execute();
    $pdo->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $pdo->rollback();
    echo "ROLLBACK:". $e->getMessage();
}


autocommit has nothing to do with PHP it's a MySQL/MariaDB setting

Can i somehow prevent transactions from being automatically opened? - YES, you can. REMOVE last two setAttribute calls. COMPLETELY

Then all queries are automatically committed, what i do not want as stated

Not "all" but only those not within an explicitly started transacton.

@DarkBee you can check the code. The problem is within PHP or the pdo/mysql driver and has nothing to do with mysql. The problem is how the driver/pdo implicitly commits or not. Not mysql.

@YourCommonSense Yes, and as stated, this is bad and not what i want.

You mean the following line: $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\', autocommit=0') which alters the database's setting?

This is good and how it works, like it or not. Still, I am genuinely puzzled by this apparent logical fallacy. Can I ask you a question? Assuming that query of yours, which is NEITHER autocommitted NOR within an explicitly opened transaction. What is the outcome you expect from this query? Should it be automatically rolled back? Or committed? When?

You get me wrong in 2 ways. I do get it works that way, but ask firstly why it changes without doc. And secondly how I can deal with my practical problem/misconception. In the end my code is an example, as stated, with a select. Nothing to roll back. Significance would be a library that you want to use that might not employ transactions. Might be that there is nothing to do about it, and that's the answer, but still a valid question to ask.

All right, I confirmed the behavior. Hence the question is fair. Still I don't get why anyone would set autocommit=0 and expect a transaction NOT started.

If you use InnoDB, even a SELECT is in a transaction. If autocommit is on, then the query starts and commits that transaction, but the transaction does happen. Transactions are useful for SELECT because you might want to make more than one query in the transaction, and ensure a "snapshot" i.e. the query results will be consistent even if other concurrent sessions are changing data.

If you use autocommit, that snapshot only lasts until the end of that single query. But it's desirable that a single query has its own snapshot, isn't it? You wouldn't want a query to see new data changes while it is executing.

@BillKarwin this question is about PDO behavior. in 7.4 beginTransaction() commits the implicitly opened (through autocommit=0) transaction. In 8.0 beginTransaction() throws an error. Like the OP already concluded, it seems there was error in PDO that has been fixed in 8.0.

@YourCommonSense, The OP asked, in part, why SELECT needs a transaction.

Yes both valid points. Imho there seems to be more to selects, snapshots and transactions according to some info I found online. See for example here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46459/putting-a-select-statement-in-a-transaction

You need to understand what PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT (autocommit=0) does. When it is enabled, every query is immediately committed to the database. When it is turned off, as is in your case, every query waits for an explicit commit, an implicit commit from a DDL query, an implicit commit from BEGIN statement (Beginning a transaction causes any pending transaction to be committed.), or for the autocommit to be turned back on.
beginTransaction() is a syntax sugar that does pretty much the same. It turns off autocommit. When you call commit you turn the autocommit back on.
Prior to PHP 8, PDO did not check whether you already had a transaction open (autocommit=0) and if you did, it simply did nothing when beginTransaction() was called.
To fix your mistake, you need to decide which approach you prefer, either switching PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT off and on manually or using beginTransaction() and commit(). Using the dedicated functions is the preferred and easier option.

Soooo, I make it, beginTransaction() internally calls inTransaction() and behaves accordingly - pre 8.0 passes this check and then BEGIN causes implicit commit, while past 8.0 throws. Bingo!
